# wpf не читает таблицу из accdb

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

сделал по этому примеру https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=RRdhgzQlC7w

```
<DataGrid
Name="maintbl"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Height="200"
Width="400"
VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

в базе такая таблица:

```
id  name1   name2   name3   dt
2   aa1     aa2     aa3     11.12.14
3   bb1     bb2     bb3     01.05.11
4   cc1     cc2     cc3     13.06.12
5   dd1     dd2     dd3     07.09.10
```

загружаю таблицу

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = D:/123/db.accdb";
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmnd = new OleDbCommand();
cmnd.CommandText = strSQL;
cmnd.Connection = conn;
cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmnd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);

maintbl.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
maintbl.Items.Refresh();
conn.Close();
```

**UPD**

```
//еще вариант
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader rd = cmnd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(rd);
maintbl.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
//тоже не работает
```

таблица не отображается. мб есть более правильный способ?

Comment: ошибка возникает или что? Пробовали току останова ставить и проверять, данные вообще приходят из БД или нет?

Comment: @tym32167 никаких ошибок. точки останов не помогают. скрипт выполняется при Window Loaded

Comment: точки  останова не должны помогать, вы из ставите  смотрите, что происходит в вашей программе. Данные из БД вообще приезжают?

Comment: @tym32167 нет. try catch говорит "Поставщик Microsoft ace oledb 12.0 не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере"

Comment: ну то есть вы даже к БД не подключаетесь. У вас провайдера данных нет видимо. Я уверен, если вы загуглите текст ошибки, вы много чего найдете

Comment: @tym32167 помогла установка AccessDatabaseEngine 2010 x86. хотя офис 2013 и система х64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогла установка AccessDatabaseEngine 2010 x86. хотя офис 2013 и система х64. оба варианта чтения таблицы работают